# Simultaneous equation arising from Eigen-vector Calculation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

The problem be found on page 9 of the following link:

http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/math108b_w2014/math108b_w2014_lecture1.pdf

As part of the soltution it is necessary to solve these simultaneous equations:

$x + y = \varphi x$

$    x = \varphi y$

They have the solutions $(\varphi y, y)$

Obviously this solution satisfies the second equation but I don't see how it satisfies the first one:

$\varphi y + y = \varphi^2 y$??

I'm sure the answer is correct so can someone please explain how the solution shown satisfies the first equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to subtract the variables to one side so you can think of the equation as $\varphi^2 y - \varphi y - y = 0$.

Earlier on the page, note that $\varphi$ is the golden ratio, $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. The quadratic equation (or just plugging $\varphi$ into the equation) tells us that $\lambda = \varphi$ is a solution to the equation $\lambda^2- \lambda - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the text $\varphi = (\sqrt{5}+1)/2,$ and thus $\varphi^2=1+\varphi.$